# How to add limited row to specific row in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I've two matrices A is 2x9 and B is 6x3,

> > A= zeros(2,9)

```
A =

 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

> > B=round(10*rand(6,3))

```
B =

 7     6     9
 6     7     8
 4     1     7
 1     1     1
 8     5     1
 3     5     1
```

by using these codes I want to add first three row of matrix B to first row of A and second three rows of matrix B to second row of matrix A by using these codes :::

```
for i=1:6

        if i<=3     

            x=x(y,:)
        else 

       end           
    end
```

I tried I don't know how inside if condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
j=1; k=1;   
for i=1:6        % loop over rows of B
  if (j > 9)     % reset your index to point to the first entry of the next row of A
    k=k+1;
    j=1;
  end
  A(k,j:j+2)=A(k,j:j+2)+B(i,:);
  j=j+3;  
end
```

If the sizes of your Matrices change you'll have to adapt the conditions and strides respectively. This is just a quick solution. I wonder if there is a more elegant way to solve this problem - there always is, when using Matlab...

Comment: exactly what I want thnx so much for your help dear el_tenedor

Comment: this is shorter I found it 
A = reshape(B',9,[])'